# JQuery ready function doesn't load what I want

Tags: jquery, html, ready

I'm trying to make sure that my JQuery ready function is working. In the long run, I want to be able to load an image once the page loads, but for now, I am trying it merely with text, and it is not working. Here is my code.

```
//inside my html

<div id= "person_image">
    <p> has not been replaced </p>
</div> 


//the ready function... this is in another file, but I know it is accessing properly 
//the made it text is displaying as it should

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("made it");
    $("person_image").html("<p> replacement string </p>");
});
```

Whenever I reload the page, nothing is changed and it still reads "has not been replaced". Am I doing something wrong with the JQuery ready function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the '#'!

```
$("person_image").html("<p> replacement string </p>");
```

should be:

```
$("#person_image").html("<p> replacement string </p>");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `#`

```
$("#person_image")
```

As of now, you are trying to access an element `<person_image>` instead of something with the `id` of `person_image`.

Comment: To expand, the `$("")` selector is essentially supposed to mimic CSS selectors, so rather than `$()` searching for a particular ID, it searches for all elements of a certain type (i.e., `<b>`, `<span>`, or in this case `<person_image>`).

Answer (score 2):

try `$("#person_image").html("<p> replacement string </p>");`
instead of
`$("person_image").html("<p> replacement string </p>");`